# How do I locally set footsepline to 0pt whenever the current page includes footnotes in a KOMA-Script class

Tags: header-footer, footnotes, koma-script, footer

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
DIV=12, % division factor
headsepline=0.8pt, % header line
footsepline=0.4pt, % footer line
numbers=noenddot, % no dots at the end of section numbering
]{scrartcl} % 11pt, a4paper (default)

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage} % KOMA-Script package for headers, footers, pagestyles
\usepackage{setspace}\setdisplayskipstretch{} % For spacing
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Multilingual support
\usepackage[babel]{microtype} % Microtypography
\usepackage{xpatch} % For patching commands
\usepackage{lipsum} % For placeholder texts

    % Replace \autodot with for "." \section headings
\xpretocmd{\sectionformat}{\def\autodot{.}}{}{\cfPatchFailed} % For headings

    % Headers
\renewcommand{\sectionmarkformat}{\thesection.\enskip} % Add period after section number in the header
\automark[section]{section}
\automark*[subsection]{subsection}

    % Shift the footer down
\ModifyLayer[addvoffset=.6ex]{scrheadings.foot.oneside}
\ModifyLayer[addvoffset=.6ex]{plain.scrheadings.foot.oneside}

    % Footers
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\normalsize\sffamily} % page number font
\ifoot*{} % inner footer
\cfoot*{\pagemark} % central footer
\ofoot*{} % outer footer

    % Footnote rule
\setfootnoterule[0.4pt]{\textwidth}

    % Footnotes
\deffootnote{0.5em}{0em}{\makebox[0.5em][l]{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}}

    % Page styles
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing
\KOMAoptions{DIV=current}
    \section{Section}
    \subsection{Subsection}
    \lipsum[1-9]\footnote{\lipsum[1][1-10]}
\end{document}
```

Here's page 2 of my MWE:

[image: MWE Page 2]

Here's my desired result for page 2:

[image: Desired Page 2]

#### What I want to do is locally set `footsepline` to be equal to `0pt` whenever the current page includes footnotes in a KOMA-Script class. How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO it does not make much sense, to remove the foot separation line only because of footnotes. However the main problem is to determine, if a footnote is printed or note. In the following I'm using a trick for this. The `\footnoterule` is only printed, if there is a footnote at this page. And in this case, I'm adding a label using:

```
\xapptocmd{\footnoterule}{\label{footrule\thepage}}{}{\PatchFailure}
```

Now, I can patch the internal command of `scrlayer-scrpage`, that is used to print the rule, to print it only, if the label is unknown:

```
\xpatchcmd\sls@hf@rule{\begingroup}{%
  \@tempswatrue
  \Ifstr{#1}{footsep}{%
    \ifcsname r@footrule\thepage\endcsname\@tempswafalse\fi
  }{}%
  \if@tempswa\begingroup
}{}{\PatchFailed}
\xpatchcmd\sls@hf@rule{\endgroup}{%
  \endgroup\fi
}{}{\PatchFailed}
```

Note: Because I'm patching an internal command, this could fail, of the internals of `scrlayer-scrpage` change.

```
\documentclass[%
DIV=12, % division factor
headsepline=0.8pt, % header line
footsepline=0.4pt, % footer line
numbers=noenddot, % no dots at the end of section numbering
]{scrartcl} % 11pt, a4paper (default)

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage} % KOMA-Script package for headers, footers, pagestyles
\usepackage{setspace}\setdisplayskipstretch{} % For spacing
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Multilingual support
\usepackage[babel]{microtype} % Microtypography
\usepackage{xpatch} % For patching commands
\usepackage{lipsum} % For placeholder texts

    % Replace \autodot with for "." \section headings
\xpretocmd{\sectionformat}{\def\autodot{.}}{}{\cfPatchFailed} % For headings

    % Headers
\renewcommand{\sectionmarkformat}{\thesection.\enskip} % Add period after section number in the header
\automark[section]{section}
\automark*[subsection]{subsection}

    % Shift the footer down
\ModifyLayer[addvoffset=.6ex]{scrheadings.foot.oneside}
\ModifyLayer[addvoffset=.6ex]{plain.scrheadings.foot.oneside}

    % Footers
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\normalsize\sffamily} % page number font
\ifoot*{} % inner footer
\cfoot*{\pagemark} % central footer
\ofoot*{} % outer footer

    % Footnote rule
\setfootnoterule[0.4pt]{\textwidth}

    % Footnotes
\deffootnote{0.5em}{0em}{\makebox[0.5em][l]{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd{\footnoterule}{\label{footrule\thepage}}{}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatletter
% NOTE: Patching an internal command is always a hack and can fail in future!
\xpatchcmd\sls@hf@rule{\begingroup}{%
  \@tempswatrue
  \Ifstr{#1}{footsep}{%
    \ifcsname r@footrule\thepage\endcsname\@tempswafalse\fi
  }{}%
  \if@tempswa\begingroup
}{}{\PatchFailed}
\xpatchcmd\sls@hf@rule{\endgroup}{%
  \endgroup\fi
}{}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing
\KOMAoptions{DIV=current}
    \section{Section}
    \subsection{Subsection}
    \lipsum[1-9]\footnote{\lipsum[1][1-10]}
\end{document}
```

[image: two pages without and with footnote]

Because of using labels, this needs at least two LaTeX runs. Maybe the detection of having a footnote on the page could be improved to work without labels.